# Retrieving MySQL values and printing them

Tags: php, html, mysql

The problem is, that when run, the script returns only the first row's `user_email` value.
I want the script to compile a list, but this is not happening.

```
//Retreive database entries for emails
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT user_email FROM users");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($fetch);
//Store input in local variables
echo "<ul>";
while ($rows) {
    echo "<li>".$rows['user_email']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: are you sure `$rows` contains all required email id's??

Comment: i am not, how would i test that? :-)

Comment: Write `print_r($rows)` in your `if` condition. That will display result.

Comment: as suggested by @Nitin print_r($rows);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your `mysql_fetch_array` as the `while`-condition, not outside.

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    echo "<li>".$rows['user_email']."</li>";
}
```

This will loop through all results from the database, rather than just repeating the first (as it's always returning true, but only for the first row).

Also, you should seriously consider converting to `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! :-) Quick response and great skillz ;-) I'll mark as answered by you, as soon as 4 minutes has passed (stackoverflow rule)

Comment: Happy to be of assistance! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Retreive database entries for emails
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT user_email FROM users");
 //Store input in local variables 
echo "<ul>"; 
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($fetch) ) {
echo "<li>".$rows['user_email']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```